# How to remove Angular ng-invalid while typing?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

The error effect (ng-invalid) shows as soon as you select a field. How can I stop this when:

1. When I haven't typed anything yet
2. When I'm still typing

Solution to either one would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ng-touched` class in addition to `ng-invalid`

See the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

```
input.one.ng-invalid { border: 2px solid red; }
input.two.ng-invalid.ng-touched { border: 2px solid red; }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('snipApp', []);
app.controller('SampleCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.inputs = {}
}]);
```

```css
input.one.ng-invalid { border: 2px solid red; }
input.two.ng-invalid.ng-touched { border: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="snipApp">
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <form name="myform">
    <div>without touched: 
      <input type="text" name="one" ng-model="inputs.one" ng-minlength="4" class="one">
    </div>
    <div>with touched: 
      <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.two" ng-minlength="4" class="two">
    </div>
    <div><pre>{{inputs|json}}</pre></div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#Arguments) settings' `updateOn` (what event should the model value be updated) and `allowInvalid` (only if you still need model value to be set with invalid value).
Set `updateOn` to `blur`. Remember you can set the ng-model-options at the top level if you dont want to repeat for every element.

Example:-

```
 <input type="number" name="num2" ng-model="num2"  ng-model-options="{'updateOn':'blur'}">
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/eNRrXr)**